# Confusion about definition of quotient topology

Tags: general-topology

I have some confusion when I learn about the definition of quotient topology.

Deﬁne $\sim$ on $[0, 1]$ by $s ∼ t$ if and only if $|s − t| = 0 $ or $ 1 $

Let $q$ be the quotient map and $$T_q =\{V \subset [0, 1]/{\sim} \mid q^{−1}(V ) \in T\}$$ where $T$ is the standard topology.

Then my question is how can $$\{[x]\mid 0\leq x<0.2\}\cup\{[1-x]\mid0.8<x<1\}$$ be the open set of $[0, 1]/{\sim}$ ?

Isn't $q^{−1}(\{[x]\mid 0\leq x<0.2\}\cup\{[x]\mid 0.8<x<1\})=[0,0.2)\cup(0.8,1)$ ?

Please let me know where I did wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Note, $\{[1-x]\mid 0.8<x<1\}$ is equal to $\{[x]\mid 0<x<0.2\}$ and so the union is just equal to the first of the two sets $\{[x]\mid 0\leq x<0.2\}$ which has preimage under $q$ equal to $\{x\mid 0\leq x<0.2\}\cup\{1\}$ which is not open. There has therefore been a mistake made somewhere either in your transcribing of the question of the subsequent edits.

If you *actually* meant that the subset $\{[x]\mid 0\leq x<0.2\}\cup \{[x]\mid 0.8<x<1\}$ is open, then this **is** true. The preimage of this subset under $q$ is equal to $$(\{x\mid 0\leq x<0.2\}\cup\{1\})\cup\{x\mid 0.8\leq x<1\}$$ (the $1$ comes from the fact that $[0]=[1]$ and so $q^{-1}([0])=\{0,1\}$) which is clearly equal to $$\{x\mid 0\leq x<0.2\} \cup \{x\mid 0.8\leq x\leq 1\} = [0,0.2)\cup(0.8,1]$$ which is an open subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: then why is [0,0.2)∪(0.8,1] open in [0,1]??

Comment: Because it is the union of open balls of radius $0.15$ with centers $0.05$ and $0.95$ respectively.